# Why does node-debug always break at _tickCallback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-inspector

It's kind of stupid question, but, I can't really figure it out for 2 hours and can't find any answer on google.

I'm trying to debug my `controller` by dropping a break point to my `save` function, on the line `var profile = req.body`:

```
function save(collectionName) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        var profile = req.body,
            query = {};
        ...
        ...
    };
}
```

However, the app always breaks inside _tickCallback function placed in `node.js` file:

```
// Run callbacks that have no domain.
// Using domains will cause this to be overridden.
function _tickCallback() {
  var callback, threw, tock;

  scheduleMicrotasks();

  while (tickInfo[kIndex] < tickInfo[kLength]) {
    tock = nextTickQueue[tickInfo[kIndex]++];
    callback = tock.callback;
    threw = true;
    try {
      callback();
      threw = false;
    } finally {
      if (threw)
        tickDone();
    }
    if (1e4 < tickInfo[kIndex])
      tickDone();
  }

  tickDone();
}
```

So, I tried to step over until it went out of the function, however, it also resumed the application without going back to my break point. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still can't find a solution. I'm not sure if it's because of the node version or not, I'm using `0.12.2`.

Comment: I'm using `0.12.4` and it's still happening. It only happens sometimes though depending on where the debugger statement is.

Answer (score 0):

I think this situation happens then you use `node-debug` command with node 0.12.*.
This is a nodejs bug https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/25266

As a workaround you can use `debugger` statement (with NI >=0.10.1. I recommend NI 0.11.0), or use iojs